# I don’t know how to open this? I’m not very tech savvy

Tags: ios, iphone, containers

file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D927D75E-D188-4F7F-AE44-2067BD750DAB/tmp/field 3.txt

I don’t know how to open this I’ve tried everything

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: “I've tried everything” Please edit your question to describe at least one of the things you've tried, in detail. Also, what does this question have to do with `new-operator`?

Comment: Sorry. I meant like new contributor or new user. First time on this site. I’m clueless. I have all these files saved on my phone and I’m trying to open them